# Path to unix socket

Tags: daemon, socket

[I'm using `p0f`](http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/p0f3/README) to fingerprint network OSs from traffic captures. `p0f` has a feature allowing it to be set up as a daemon and listen in the background for a connection from a `p0f-client` (ie: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/p0f/0.1.1)

To set up `p0f` as a daemon I should run ie:

```
p0f -i eth0 -s path/to/unix_socket
```

But I don't get the part about `path/to/unix_socket`. I'm relatively new to Linux and I'm use to having servers apps setting up their sockets themselves?

Can anyone indicate how to set up `p0f` as a daemon?

Answer (score 7):

The `path/to/unix_socket` is a filesystem location that you can choose to hold a socket for communication from a client to the daemon. Think of a socket as being a bi-directional pipe or file that has a reader/writer (listener) and a writer/reader (talker). The `p0f` daemon will create the socket in the place that you specify.

As concrete examples, it could be `/tmp/p0fsock` or `/var/run/p0f`, or indeed anywhere else in the filesystem that your daemon has permissions to create a listening socket. The only caveat is that the clients must know the socket address (i.e. path within the filesystem) to communicate with the daemon.